# Difference between pubspec.lock and pubspec.yaml

Tags: dart, dart-pub

What is the difference between pubspec.yaml and pubspec.lock? Both are holding the dependencies versions.

Comment: Typically a lockfile is *more specific* (exact versions, not version ranges), and includes all of the *transitive dependencies* (not just direct dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

> The first time you get a new dependency for your package, pub downloads the latest version of it that’s compatible with your other dependencies. It then locks your package to always use that version by creating a lockfile. This is a file named pubspec.lock that pub creates and stores next to your pubspec. It lists the specific versions of each dependency (immediate and transitive) that your package uses.

~ [source](https://dart.dev/guides/packages#upgrading-a-dependency)

In `pubspec.yaml` there are only packages and versions, which you need to use. In pubspec.lock there are also packages and versions which you need and which each of package that you use needs.

Answer (score 0):

- The pubspec.yaml file is used to declare the dependencies and configuration for a Dart package, while the pubspec.lock file is automatically generated by the Pub package manager to lock the version of each dependency used in the project.
- The pubspec.lock file ensures that all members of a team, or a CI/CD pipeline, use the same dependencies, preventing version conflicts and ensuring the reproducibility of builds.
- The pubspec.yaml file is manually maintained and can be changed to update the project's dependencies or configuration.